# Этот javascript

Tags: javascript, userjs

```
var i;
var d = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");

window.onload = function klatz(){
    for(i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
        if((d[i].getAttribute("href") == "#") && (d[i].getAttribute("onclick") != "LoadPartyRankings(1);") && (d[i].value == "►")){
            d[i].click();
            break;
        } else {
            alert("NOPE");
        }
    }
}
```

Документ - одна большая таблица с еще несколькими друг в друга вложенными таблицами, и в самой глубокой таблице в ячейке есть ссылка `<a href="#" onclick="LoadSoloRankings(1);">►</a>`. При каждом нажатии аргумент инкрементируется. Чтобы следить за происходящим добавил alert, но появляются первая проблема: document.ready = ... не работает вместо window.onload = ..., при window.onload выходит проверка раньше времени, и вторая проблема:  не находится сама ссылка - возился хрен знает сколько, но результат нулевой. И еще остаётся вопрос: обновляется ли страница при таком значении href?

Comment: Вместо     d[i].value используйте     d[i].innerHTML

Comment: Спасибо, это заработало, но по-прежнему происходит лишь один клик, с этой # ничего не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставь скрипт перед закрывающим тегом body и не надо мучатся с windows.onload. Значение атрибута href # это хэш(якорь), страница не перезагрузится, а прокрутится к началу документа. Насчет поиска ссылки непонятно совсем, приведите хотя бы примерно структуру документа

Comment: Ссылку нужную нашел, спасибо andreyqin. Скрипт в tampermonkey, так что в html код добавить не вариант. За разъяснения про хэш спасибо, а то дерганый значок обновления страницы при нажатии меня сбивал с толку:) Убрал window.onload, добавил setInterval(klatz, 500);, все заработало, вопрос можно считать решенным, спасибо.